# Create a Glue table from a csv file with extra commas

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

In AWS S3 I have a CSV-file with delimiter “,” where address column contains commas:

… ,pharm_email,**pharm_address**,pharm_address_id, …

…  ,byaroza_1@compharm.com,**"West Loreanton, B. 13281"**,8687,  …

When I create a Glu table by crawler, obviously, it is populated incorrectly.

I *created a classifier* with the following settings: Delimiter ‘ , ’ and Quote symbol  “, the rest is default.
After the crawler  with this classifier  run the result was the same.

I changed the table properties: set Serde serialization lib to  *"org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde”* and *deleted delimiter in Serde parameters*.

After the new crawler run I got the same incorrect table with properties set back to “org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe”

Can I handle this problem in AWS?